# asp.net MVC web application date picker doesn't work

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

This is my Create.cshtml file

```
@model Bartering.Models.Advertisement


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">

</script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" 

type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">

</script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" 

type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Advertisement", FormMethod.Post,  new { enctype="multipart/form-data" })) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>TASK</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Task_For)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Task_For)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Task_For)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Department)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Department,(SelectList)ViewBag.CategoryList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Department)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Attachment)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="file" id="MyFile" runat="server" />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Attachment)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
        </div>
       @inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<System.DateTime?> 
       @Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()), new { @class = "datefield" })      
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
        </div>


        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Post"  />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

this is my Advertisement model class

```
 using System;
 using System.Drawing; // Image type is in this namespace
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
 using System.ComponentModel;

 namespace Bartering.Models
 {
        public class Advertisement
        {
            [Key]
            public int ID { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100)]
            public string Task_For { get; set; }

            public Guid OwnerID { get; set; }

            public string UserName { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public string Department { get; set; }


            public byte[] Attachment { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(200)]

            public string Description { get; set; }

            public int Count { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Date")]

            [DataType(DataType.DateTime,ErrorMessage="Date non valid")]
            [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yy}",ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
            [Required]
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }


        }
 }
```

when I run my application it gives the following error

```
The 'inherits' keyword is not allowed when a 'model' keyword is used.

Line 66:        @inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<System.DateTime?>
```

I want to add a date picker to add the date.how do I fix this please help me to fix this.

Comment: You cannot use both inherit and model keyword together...Check out this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/thread/233633/error-the-inherits-keyword-is-not-allowed-when-a-mo.aspx

Comment: I believe, jquery-ui library is missing.
Please try to add that let us know in case if it is working

Comment: thanks for your reply but this is not the case..@Farzi I refer that link but without using both I cant do it

Comment: Is any method to do this without using both key words???

Answer (score 0):

In your view you have

```
  @inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<System.DateTime?> 
       @Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") :
```

Just remove inherits line "@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage "

UPDATE after comment

Please read about inherits http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/01/13/razor-tip-2-inheritance-amp-configuration.aspx

Simply talkin inherits let know razor of which time would be your @Model property.
To make date picker work you have @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date) and it will render  (Html5 date picker) it will work in modern browsers.

To make you second example working please follow format

```
@Html.TextBox("name", "value", new {type="date"})
```

Comment: @user2844981 have you fixed? or do you need help ?:)

Comment: I didn't fix it I need a help

Comment: @user2844981 can you please explain what is not working when you remove inherits?